# %Like% Query in spring JpaRepository for N fields

Tags: java, database, spring

What I want to do as native query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%param1%' AND col1 LIKE '%param2%';
```

But the thing is I can get 1..N params, how would I achieve this?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "random")
public class Random implements Serializable {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String col1;
}

public interface IRandomDAO extends JpaRepository<Random, Long>{
    public List<Random> findByCol1Containing(String params);

}

public interface IRandomService {
    public List<Random> findByCol1Containing(Set<String> params);
}

@Service
public class RandomServiceImpl implements IRecetaService {
    @Autowired
    private IRecetaDAO recetaDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Random> findByCol1In(Set<String> params) {      
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Random> query = cb.createQuery(Random.class);
        Root<Random> random= query.from(Random.class);

        Path<String> paramsPath = random.get("col1");

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String param: params) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(paramsPath , param));
        }
        query.select(random)
            .where(cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

        return entityManager.createQuery(query)
            .getResultList();    
    }
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:4200" })
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class RandomRestController {

    @Autowired
    private IRandomService randomService;   

    @GetMapping("/random")
    public ResponseEntity<?> find(@RequestParam String params) {
        String[] search = null;
        Set<String> searchParams = new HashSet<>();
        if (params.contains("-")) {
            search = params.split("-");
            for (int i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
                // filling the set with any number of items
                searchParams.add("%" + search[i] + "%");
            }
        } else {
            searchParams.add("%" + params + "%");
        }
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        List<Random> listRandom = null;
        listRandom = randomService.findByCol1In(searchParams);
        if (!listRandom.isEmpty()) {
            response.put("mensaje", "found it");
            response.put("receta", listRandom);
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        response.put("message", "not found");
        response.put("word", searchParams.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
}
```

So the problem is that with this code i get a query result like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%param1%';

SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%param2%';

SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE ...N params;
```

How can i achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%param1%' AND col1 LIKE '%param2%' AND col1 LIKE '%Nparams%';
```

If I did something wrong with the question I am sorry, this is my first post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a quick glance, you're using 'or' instead of 'and'.. Can you correct and see if that gives expected result? This: cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))

Comment: That was it @Jayr, it works as i want no, thank you so much!!